# How to remove multiple selected values from a selected list box on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm very new to JQuery. I have written a code for Adding & Removing code from a selected list box. Here, Adding first three values from different select list box is done but, I couldn't achieve deleting those three values that i have added.
HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div>
    <select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5"></select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
    var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
    var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
    $('#add-category').click(function () {
        $(
            '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
        ).each(function () {
            // $('#selected-lst-values').append($(this).val());
            $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
        });
    });
    $('#remove-category').click(function () {
        $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function () {
            $('#selected-lst-values')
                .find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"')
                .remove();
        });
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pkprabu/x3feywjr/)

Answer (score 0):

You are *so* close! If you check the console log, you'll see that the `.find()` can't find the target, as you missed the closing square bracket.

All you need is:

```
.find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
  var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
  var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
  $('#add-category').click(function() {
    $(
      '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
    ).each(function() {
      // $('#selected-lst-values').append($(this).val());
      $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
    });
  });
  $('#remove-category').click(function() {
    $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function() {
      $('#selected-lst-values')
        .find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
        .remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div>
  <select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

I've also created an updated working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/f3wntyn9/).

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**:

To remove the last three values, and then be able to remove the *previous* three values until all values are gone, you need to make use of the CSS selector `last-of-type`:

```
var the_index = $(this).val() - 1;
$('#selected-lst-values').find('option:nth-last-of-type(' + the_index + ')').remove();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
 var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
 var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
 $('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
   '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
   $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
 });
 $('#remove-category').click(function() {
     $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function() {
     var the_index = $(this).val() - 1;
         $('#selected-lst-values')
                .find('option:nth-last-of-type(' + the_index + ')')
                .remove();
     });
 });
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,.select-manage-category1,.select-manage-category2{
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 margin-right:4px;
}
p{clear:left;text-align:center;}

#selected-lst-values{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
<div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p></div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

This works based off of removing the final three options in the `<select>` list on click of the button, and as you add three at a time, the final three options will be the ones that you have just added.

I've updated my fiddle to showcase this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/f3wntyn9/2/).

Note that if you prefer, you can also remove **all** categories at once with just `.find('option').remove();`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Obsidian Age. But, It allows me to delete only the last values i selected. i.e First i select three values, and then i select another three values. Now, There would be 6 values in the select list box. So, When i click "Remove Category" button it removes only the last three values and not other three values on next click. But, I want those to be removed on next click.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to cover this. See the edit :)